# Need to know exact geolocation where Google stores Cloud Storage content

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud-storage

Due to the nature of our business, we basically need to disclose *where in the globe* the files uploaded by our users are located.

In other words, we need the *exact address* where the data storage that keeps these files is located.

We're using Google Firebase's Cloud Storage and, even though [they mention which city each location option refers to](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#default-cloud-location), we are unable to check the exact address.

The bucket that corresponds to our Google Cloud Storage is currently configured as: `us (multiple regions in United States)`, which I suppose makes it even worse to pinpoint where the data resides. But that is an easy fix: we can simply start from scratch selecting a specific region as our storage location.

The main issue, however, is that, even if selecting a specific location, we can't really know the address where those files will be stored.

Has anyone ever come across something like this?

[I tried getting support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/cases) in my project's Google Cloud Platform, but apparently I need to purchase it. And I'm afraid that they won't be able to help me.

In case someone has contacted their support and got this answer, please let me know.

Comment: If there is some particular compliance reason why address level information is needed, adding it to your question will help transform this from a question that seems to ask for irrelevant info into a clear "help me achieve compliance XXX" question.

Comment: e.g. if this is for ISO27001 needs, https://services.google.com/fh/files/misc/may_2021_gci_iso27001_certificate.pdf lists the infomation needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you store data in GCS, even in a regional bucket, Google does not make any guarantee which zone(s) within the region the data is stored in, nor is this visible. Different zones in a region can be at a different street address, so street-address level location data is unavailable, even if you get the datacenter addresses by finding the datacenters on Google maps (you could [start here](https://www.google.com/about/datacenters/locations/)).

Comment: Thanks, @David. I followed your suggestion and posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69778207/how-to-comply-with-usc-2257a-while-using-google-storage).